How to achieve Hyperparameter Tuning with TensorFlow 2's Object Detection API?
I have managed to create a custom object detection model using TF2's Object Detection API using this tutorial: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html, however, it's performing really poorly. I've tried to play around with the parameters in the configuration file but have yet to achieve a well-performing model that can accurately detect the objects. I want to know if there's a way to achieve hyperparameter optimization using methods such as Grid Search or Random Search to help me get the best set of hyperparameters for my model. Despite doing a lot of research, I haven't been able to come across any articles that show me how to achieve this. Also, if it helps, the amount of training images I'm working with is 1250. This is my configuration file currently:
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 13
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 720
        width: 1280
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_mobilenet_v2_keras"
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      min_depth: 16
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.029999999329447746
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.9700000286102295
          center: true
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
          train: true
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.009999999776482582
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.9700000286102295
            center: true
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
            train: true
          }
        }
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.800000011920929
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.599999904632568
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.20000000298023224
        max_scale: 0.949999988079071
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.33329999446868896
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993922529e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.6000000238418579
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
        use_static_shapes: false
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
          delta: 1.0
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 2.0
          alpha: 0.75
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 5
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.08
          total_steps: 2500
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.01
          warmup_steps: 250
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.8999999761581421
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "D:/mywork/TensorFlow2/NEW/Object_Detection/Training/test_model/pre-trained_model/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 2500
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "D:/mywork/TensorFlow2/NEW/Object_Detection/BusModel/Data/labels.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
  input_path: "D:/mywork/TensorFlow2/NEW/Object_Detection/BusModel/tfrecord_files/train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "D:/mywork/TensorFlow2/NEW/Object_Detection/BusModel/Data/labels.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
  input_path: "D:/mywork/TensorFlow2/NEW/Object_Detection/BusModel/tfrecord_files/train.record/test.record"
  }
}

